# Next tailwindcss google font link tag not applying

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, google-fonts

So, using the @import in the tailwind css file works but using the  tag in _document.jsx fails to work.

Chrome dev tools show that the classes are applied but the fallback is applied and not the downloaded google font.

Unsure why this isnt. Am I missing a gotcha or something

Tailwind config

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
    },
    fontFamily: {
      fun: ['"Lobster Two"', "cursive"],
      pro: ['"Source Serif Pro"', "serif"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/typography"), require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

_document.tsx

```
import Document, {
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  DocumentContext,
} from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
            crossOrigin="true"
          />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster+Two:wght@400;700&family=Source+Serif+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by not properly configuring tailwind rather than downloading the font in Next.js. For Tailwind config, inside the **fontFamily** property you can enter three keys:

- sans
- serif
- mono

See the docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing-your-theme).

Tailwind config:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
    },
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['"Lobster Two"'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/typography"), require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

If you want to use arbitrary values like **fun** and **pro** check out [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-values)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in your global.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lobster+Two?query=lobster+two");
```

and delete this one from your _document.tsx

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster+Two:wght@400;700&family=Source+Serif+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
```